# Winforms: Boolean logic not working properly

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, boolean-logic

My situation is that I have Form 1 and Form 2. In Form 1 I have button1 and button2. I define a `bool dtgmb` to be false throughout Form1. However, if button2 is clicked then, `dtgmb` is true.

In Form 2 I have 1 DTG and button3 where all the data of the rows have been defined. Therefore, I run the instance whereby if `dtgmb` is false (button 1 is clicked), then display content of `object[] rows` and if `dtgmb` is true (button2 is clicked), then display content of `object[] rows1` instead. Then button3 will be clicked to return to Form1.

However, if I click button1 first, then subsequently return to Form 1 and click button2, Form2 will show display content of `object[] rows` for both times. Then if I close the app and restart again and this time I click button2 first, then subsequently return to Form 1 and click button1, Form2 will show display content of `object[] rows1` for both times.

Below is my code:

**Form 1**

```
public bool dtgmb = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Forms saved in class called FormsCollection
    FormsCollection.Form1.Hide();
    FormsCollection.Form2.Show();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsCollection.Form1.Hide();
    dtgmb = true;
    FormsCollection.Form2.Show();
}
```

**Form 2**

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   stuff(FormsCollection.Form1);
 }   

public void stuff(Form1 form)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn check = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn check1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    dataGridView4.ColumnCount = 1;
    dataGridView4.Columns[0].Width = 380;
    dataGridView4.Columns[0].Name = "Item";
    string[] row1 = new string[] { "Tables" };
    string[] row2 = new string[] { "Chairs" };
    string[] row3 = new string[] { "Lamps" };
    string[] row4 = new string[] { "Pillows" };
    string[] row5 = new string[] { "Blankets" };
    object[] rows = new object[] { row1, row2, row3, row4, row5 };
    object[] rows1 = new object[] { row1, row2, row3, row4 };

    if (form.dtgmb == false)
        foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
        {
            this.dataGridView4.Rows.Add(rowArray);
        }
    else
        foreach (string[] rowArray in rows1)
        {
            this.dataGridView4.Rows.Add(rowArray);
        }

    check.HeaderText = "Pass";
    check1.HeaderText = "Fail";
    dataGridView4.Columns.Add(check);
    dataGridView4.Columns.Add(check1);
}
```

Comment: maybe because you forgot to call stuff() again and therefore, Form2 is not refreshed?

Comment: Because you do not set `dtgmb` to `false` in `button1_Click`?

Comment: You are using `static` variable. The value of `dtgmb` will depend on the last value you set it to. It will only reset back to default value of `false` upon restarting of the application.

Comment: Hi Antoine and Gserg, I tried both of yall suggesstion but still no change.

Comment: Hi John. Correct me if I'm wrong. Hmm, what I understand about using static is because this boolean always call the button, where the button properties will never change. Hence, that's why I left it as static. If I remove the static, then the error of object reference occur and I'm  not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to `dtgmb` being marked as static. This means that all the instances regardless they life span will share the same value.
Static variables are initialized when the application starts to their native default values (e.g. integers are initialized to zero, while booleans to false).

If you remove the static modifier, you will need to invoke the `stuff` method with a reference to a form. Since you are not showing us where you call stuff, I post here the refactor of what you posted.

**Form1.cs**:

```
public bool dtgmb = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Forms saved in class called FormsCollection
    FormsCollection.Form1.Hide();
    FormsCollection.Form2.Show();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsCollection.Form1.Hide();
    dtgmb = true;
    FormsCollection.Form2.Show();
}
```

and **Form2.cs**

```
public void stuff(Form1 form)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn check = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn check1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    dataGridView4.ColumnCount = 1;
    dataGridView4.Columns[0].Width = 380;
    dataGridView4.Columns[0].Name = "Item";
    string[] row1 = new string[] { "Tables" };
    string[] row2 = new string[] { "Chairs" };
    string[] row3 = new string[] { "Lamps" };
    string[] row4 = new string[] { "Pillows" };
    string[] row5 = new string[] { "Blankets" };
    object[] rows = new object[] { row1, row2, row3, row4, row5 };
    object[] rows1 = new object[] { row1, row2, row3, row4 };

    if (form.dtgmb == false)
        foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
        {
            this.dataGridView4.Rows.Add(rowArray);
        }
    else
        foreach (string[] rowArray in rows1)
        {
            this.dataGridView4.Rows.Add(rowArray);
        }

    check.HeaderText = "Pass";
    check1.HeaderText = "Fail";
    dataGridView4.Columns.Add(check);
    dataGridView4.Columns.Add(check1);
}
```

Keep in mind that sharing fields directly is not a good practice, but this is good to understand where the problem lies.

**EDIT following the comments**

It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Your code does not work as you are trying to pass a type as a formal argument of a function. I refactored your code in order to compile (but I do not understand how it should behave):

**Program.cs**

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        new Form1().Show();
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
```

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool dtgmb = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FormCollection.Form1 = this;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Forms saved in class called FormsCollection
        FormCollection.Form1.Hide();
        FormCollection.Form2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormCollection.Form1.Hide();
        dtgmb = true;
        FormCollection.Form2.Show();
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormCollection.Form1 = null;
    }
}

public static class FormCollection
{
    public static Form1 Form1;
    public static Form2 Form2;

}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FormCollection.Form2 = this;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stuff(FormCollection.Form1);
    }

    public void stuff(Form1 form)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn check = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn check1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        dataGridView4.ColumnCount = 1;
        dataGridView4.Columns[0].Width = 380;
        dataGridView4.Columns[0].Name = "Item";
        string[] row1 = new string[] { "Tables" };
        string[] row2 = new string[] { "Chairs" };
        string[] row3 = new string[] { "Lamps" };
        string[] row4 = new string[] { "Pillows" };
        string[] row5 = new string[] { "Blankets" };
        object[] rows = new object[] { row1, row2, row3, row4, row5 };
        object[] rows1 = new object[] { row1, row2, row3, row4 };

        if (form.dtgmb == false)
            foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
            {
                this.dataGridView4.Rows.Add(rowArray);
            }
        else
            foreach (string[] rowArray in rows1)
            {
                this.dataGridView4.Rows.Add(rowArray);
            }

        check.HeaderText = "Pass";
        check1.HeaderText = "Fail";
        dataGridView4.Columns.Add(check);
        dataGridView4.Columns.Add(check1);
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormCollection.Form2 = null;
    }
}
```

Please note that the code above has several issues: one for all it relies upon how forms are initialized.

Comment: Hi Pier. Appreciate the explanation. With your code, there are still no changes. Hence, I have edited my code above to show how I call `stuff()`. Hope you can help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi Pier. In all honesty most of my codes are copy pasted from other forums/websites that I had found and I have yet to truly understand the reasoning of doing so and so. With your codes, errors occurred and yeah, definitely have to do with how I initialized these forms under `FormsCollection.cs`. I will most likely revised my overall codes. Thanks for your effort sir.